# How to source a env in crontab?

Tags: python, cron

I need to source a venv file in crontab file

Dry run in terminal,
source a env

```
 source myenv/bin/activate
```

Run Python file

```
 /path/to/file python.py
```

What i have tried so far

```
  * * * * * /home/user/myenv/bin/python /path/to/file python.py>/path/to/anotherfile
```

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you call a sh script in the crontab that source your env first and then run your python program?

Answer (score 0):

You can `source` the `activate` file, and then run the script:

```
* * * * * . /path/to/venv/activate && python /path/to/file python.py >/path/to/anotherfile
```

Note the `.` (which is analogous to `source` but is POSIX). We need it because the `cron` is usually run using `sh` (whatever that symlinks to in your system), so we should take portability into account.

If the script has the shebang as `#!/usr/bin/env python` and is executable, you can run it directly:

```
* * * * * . /path/to/venv/activate && /path/to/file python.py >/path/to/anotherfile
```

Comment: did this `* * * * * . /path/to/venv/activate && python /path/to/file python.py >/path/to/anotherfile
`   but  source is not happening because i am getting import error.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, working for me. Can you please check from terminal directly?

Comment: when i run the source  /path/to/venv/activate and then run the code. it is running fine. but when i try this in cron . source is not getting activated